# Why isn't the "Interesting" tab available under the "Questions" page?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, tabs, interesting-page

A while ago I ran into the `Interesting` tab, and wondered how come I was not aware of it before.
After playing around a little, I realized that this tab is available only at the Home page which I did not visit very often (I was using the `Questions` page).

My question is, How come the `Interesting` page is not under `Questions`? This is where I would expect to find it...